# Partial css in react appearing in the whole app

Tags: reactjs, sass

I have a component in react called `ContentPage`.

The component has its own css called `ContentPage.css`.

I am obviously importing it into `ContentPage.js` and the css is imported only in this component.

From my understanding its styles should be applied only to `ContentPage` component. Instead of it the styles from `ContentPage.css` are visible across the application in non-related components.

How to apply the styles only in this component?

Here's the css:

```
@import '../../../Variables.scss';
@import '../../../Mixins.scss';

table {
    @include table-border;

    tr {
        @include table-border;


        td, th { 
            @include table-border;

            width: 15%; 
            padding: 2%;

            &:first-child { width: 15%; }
            &:last-child { width: 60%; }
        }
    }
}
```

and the component import:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Styles/ContentPage.css';
```

Comment: have you created the app using `create-react-app`? if yes then `create-react-app` doesn't come with CSS MODULE support that you are talking about. you have to configure your build process to add that support

Comment: @nickornotto What do you mean by "partial CSS"? You want to be confident, that your styles won't be used by another component? Then use CSS modules. Do you want to pack styles separately with component? You can't do this with SASS, in this case, you need to use JSS, look at styled-components.

Answer (score 0):

When you import a .css threw a component at the moment of the compilation / build it will create a single bundle.css file which will be used by your application.

If you want to provide stylesheet just for your component you have to do like this :

```
import React from 'react';

const divStyle = {
  margin: '40px',
  border: '5px solid pink'
};
const pStyle = {
  fontSize: '15px',
  textAlign: 'center'
};

const Box = () => (
  <div style={divStyle}>
    <p style={pStyle}>Get started with inline style</p>
  </div>
);

export default Box;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the webpack config to ensure that the css becomes component-wise.

See when webpack bundles it takes your CSS file and adds it to a single CSS file or if you are using style-loader then it add to your header.Since CSS does not know anything about your component we need to ensure that CSS class that you have for your component is scoped for your component only.

So how do we achieve this?

We append a hash or some unique value to your class name to ensure that a class of **wrapper** defined in **Header.css** is different from **wrapper** in **Navbar.css**.

The way we do this is :

in your webpack config file where you are testing for **css** you might be just addng the **css-loader** **like this:**

```
test: /\.(s?)css$/,
use: [
  'style-loader',
  'css-loader',
 ]
```

**change it to this:**

```
test: /\.(s?)css$/,
use: [
  'style-loader',
  {
   loader: 'css-loader',
   options: {
            importLoaders: 1,
            modules: true,
            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
     },
  }
```

Here **modules:true** will tell webpack to treat each css/scss file as a module to ensure that it adds the hash.
**localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',** will give the format of the hash else wepack will give its own hash and replace you class name.

Comment: What is webpack? I don't have such config file within the app @abhay I mean I can see webpack module but can't see webpack.config anywhere

Comment: create another webpack config file and in your scripts run webpack with config pointing to the above file. also add a class rahter than targeting the element as the CSS gets concatenated.